# Can anyone share original IO80211FAMILY kext for OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

Can anyone share original IO80211FAMILY kext file for OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5 as I by mistake deleted it and now my WiFi has stopped working.

I could not find it on Google, please if you have the 10.8.5, please share original file.

Comment: Why don't you just [reinstall the OS](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18872?locale=en_US)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the 10.8.5 combo updater, from https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1676?locale=en_GB

This will ensure all updates since 10.8.0 are applied.

Comment: You can also extract the kext from the combo updates manually.

Comment: @CousinCocaine - for sure, but running it would double-check everything else while you're at it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Your solution worked... thank you very much and i am accepting your answer! Thanks again!